# How to extract the delimiter in large csv file from s3 through pandas

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

How to extract the delimiter in large csv file from s3 through python pandas.

**Input data -**

```
id|name|age|address
```

**Output result -**

```
|
```

**Code tried:**

```
from detect_delimiter import detect

s3 = session.client('s3')
file = s3.get_object(Bucket="test", Key="input/csvfolder/test_123456789.csv")
csv_string = file["Body"].read()
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(csv_string),sep=",",encoding="cp1252",chunksize=1)
print(detect(df))
```

**Error :**

```
AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need full file content to detect seperator.
Instead, can you try to read the csv file normally (without pandas) and pass only first line to "detect". Something like below.

```
from detect_delimiter import detect
file = open('mycsv.csv', 'r')
print(detect(file.readline()))
file.close()
```

**It outputs:**

```
,
```

as my file is comma seperated.

Comment: Your solution worked for me but only when I download the file from the s3 path to my local computer. Do you know any way to use the open function with a s3 path directory?